# Increase parallel copy in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to perform ADF copy activity from CosmosDB to Azure Blob Container. The degree of copy parallelism is always 1, even if I specify a greater value. what determines the parallelism value and how do I increase it ? . If the copy is from CosmosDB to another CosmosDB , I could achieve more than 1 parallel copies. But when the sink is blob container, I'm facing the issue.

Currently, the pipeline is writing into single file in Azure Blob Container. But I don't see an option to write multiple output files , incase if that helps to increase parallel copy.

Comment: what is the data type that you are copying is it a SQL data?

Comment: @SallyDabbah I'm not sure if I got your question correctly. But  I'm using Azure CosmosDB (Sql API) as source dataset and ADLS2 (json format) for sink dataset.

Comment: Also I added an extra detail to the question about the single output file. I'm not sure if that is causing any issue

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#parallel-copy),

> The degree of copy parallelism in the copy activity means the maximum number of threads that copy activity uses to copy the data parallelly from the source to sink to increase the throughput.

It won’t generate multiple files in the sink.

It will only increase the throughput of the activity by copying concurrently using the number of threads we specify.

The **copy activity only copies our source table or data to only single file** despite the **increase or decrease of degree of copy parallelism** because these two actions have no relationship between them apart from the throughput.

If you want to copy multiple files from single cosmos db container, you can try a `ForEach activity` with certain inputs from cosmos db dataset **with a copy activity inside it** which copies the input data to a single file on each iteration of forEach. You can **set the number of copies** in this by giving value to **Batch count of forEach**.

[image: ref1]

Please go through this [link](https://azurelib.com/foreach-activity-in-azure-data-factory-with-practical-example/#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20foreach%20activity%20pencil%20icon%20to%20edit,current%20item%20foreach%20iteration%20by%20using%20%40item%20%28%29.) from **azurelib** by **Deepak Goyal** to learn more about **Parallel execution of copy activity using ForEach.**

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mentioned multiple output files to confirm that is not causing the issue. But the question is to achieve parallel copy using Copy activity.

Comment: In copy activity under setting there is option called **Degree of copy parallelism** which determines the parallel thread that will be used. for more information refer this [Document](https://nishantrana.me/2021/05/25/write-batch-size-data-integration-unit-and-degree-of-copy-parallelism-in-azure-data-factory-for-dynamics-crm-365-dataset/)